# Combine two SELECT queries with UNION, where one of them is a JOIN

Tags: sql, select, union

I want to combine two select statements using UNION, but it's not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT content
    FROM tbl_jokes 
    JOIN tbl_jokes_relationships ON tbl_jokes_relationships.rid_jokes = tbl_jokes.id_jokes
    WHERE tbl_jokes_relationships.rid_jokes_categories ='1'
    ORDER BY id_jokes DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tbl_jokes 
    WHERE rid_jokes_categories='blondinenwitze'
";
```

Its not working, I tested the two `select` statements without UNION and the are showing the results I want to, thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose the same columns.  Something like this:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM tbl_jokes j JOIN
     tbl_jokes_relationships jr
     ON jr.rid_jokes = j.id_jokes
WHERE jr.rid_jokes_categories = 1
UNION
SELECT j.*
FROM tbl_jokes j
WHERE j.rid_jokes_categories = 'blondinenwitze'
```

It seems silly to use `union` for this, unless it meets some performance objective:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM tbl_jokes j LEFT JOIN
     tbl_jokes_relationships jr
     ON jr.rid_jokes = j.id_jokes
WHERE jr.rid_jokes_categories = 1 OR
      j.rid_jokes_categories = 'blondinenwitze';
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` in a subquery does nothing.  If you want the results ordered, you have to specify the `ORDER BY` for the outermost `SELECT`.

Comment: can you tell me what j.* and jr means?

Comment: j and jr are each an alias, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp, for a table in that query. j.* will select all the columns within that table.